# How to find TMax without using shifts

Tags: c++, c, binary, logic, bit-manipulation

Using ONLY

```
 ! ~ & ^ | +
```

How can I find out if a 32 bit number is TMax?

TMax is the maximum, two's complement number.

My thoughts so far have been:

```
int isTMax(int x)
{
  int y = 0;
  x = ~x;
  y = x + x;
  return !y;
}
```

That is just one of the many things I have unsuccessfully have tried but I just cant think of a property of TMax that would give me TMax back. Like adding tmax to itself would be unique compared to all the other integers.

---

Here is the actual problem:

```
/*
 * isTMax - return 1 if x is the maximum, two's complement number,
 *     and 0 return otherwise. 
 *   Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | +
 *   Max ops: 10
 *   Rating: 1
 */
int isTMax(int x) {
  int y = 0;
  x = ~x;
  y = x + x;

  return !y;
}
```

int is 32 bits so the max signed would probably be 0x7FFFFFFF

Comment: What is TMax? The maximum unsigned (or signed) integer?

Comment: I think you'll need to elaborate on what TMax is.

Comment: Maximum two's complement number. Sorry for not elaborating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?
0x7FFFFFFF is the maximum positive signed 32 bit two's complement number.

```
int isTMax(int x){
    return !(x ^ 0x7FFFFFFF);
}
```

I am not sure, you may need to cast it to unsigned for it to work.

Comment: This works perfectly thank you very much I dont know why I was trying to overthink it.

Comment: Is this answer acceptable? I was assuming constants were not allowed either. If so, then yes, this is the best solution.

Comment: Constants are allowed because we assume its a 32 bit number since in C ints are 32 in length.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there is no way to determine if a particular value is the max value of a *signed* type without already knowing the maximum value of that type and making a direct comparison. This is because signed expressions experience undefined behavior on overflow. If there were an answer to your question, it would imply the existence of an answer to a serious unsolved problem that's been floating around on SO for some time: how to programmatically determine the max value for a given signed type.

Comment: overflow is not handled so only 32 bits will be represented if it goes over its lost.

Comment: No, it invokes undefined behavior and you cannot assume anything about the program's output. Whoever came up with this assignment apparently does not know C...

Answer (score 4):

Spend 3 hours on this question. I know this comes from csapp's data lab and its newest requirement is

```
1. Integer constants 0 through 255 (0xFF), inclusive. You are
  not allowed to use big constants such as 0xffffffff
....

* isTmax - returns 1 if x is the maximum, two's complement number,
 *     and 0 otherwise
 *   Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | +
 *   Max ops: 10
 *   Rating: 1
```

So, shift operator (`<<`/`>>` and `0x7FFFFFFF` from the accepted answer is forbidden now)

Below is my way:

TDD-style:

```
isTmax(2147483647) == isTmax(0b011111111111...1) == 1
isTmax(2147483646) == isTmax(0b011111111111...0) == 0
isTmax(-1) == isTmax(0b111111111...1) == 0
isTmax(-2147483648) == isTmax(0b100000000...0) == 0
```

the return should be either `0` or `1`. In c, `!` on all nonzero will return `0`. So `!` is a must, otherwise, we cannot guarantee to get `0` for all numbers.

#### First naive try:

because `0b0111111...1` (aka `2147483647`) is the only argument that should make `isTmax` return `1` and `2147483647 + 1` should be `10000000...0`(aka `-2147483648`)

`0b011111111...1 xor 0b1000000000...0` is `0b11111111111...111`. Because we must use `!`,  what we hope to see is `0`(aka `0b0000000000000...0`). Obviously, apply *logic not*(aka `!`) to `0b1111111...1`), then we will get `0b000000000000`):

```
!(~(x ^ (x + 1))
```

let's printf it

```
void print(int x)
{
     printf("%d\n", !(~(x ^ (x + 1))));
}
int main() {
        print (2147483647);
        print(2147483646);
        print(-1);
        print(-2147483648);
}
```

> 1

> 0

> 1

> 0

[**`live demo`**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ht6xwAXcLIMaTrSE)

Not bad, only `-1` doesn't work as we expected.

#### second try:

Let's compare `-1` and `2147483647`

11111111111111111111111111111111                
01111111111111111111111111111111

We can find `-1 + 1 = 0` while `2147483647 + 1 = -2147483648`. Emphasize again, what we want is diff `-1` and `2147483647`, because both of them return `1` as above shows. Look back to the property of *logic not* in c: *all nonzero will return 0*, so `!-2147483648 == 0` and `!(-1 + 1) != 0`. Just modify left part of `x ^ (x + 1)`(`x`) into `x + !(x + 1)`. If x is `2147483647`, `x + !(x + 1)` will equal to `x`.

Run again:

```
void print(int x)
{
    printf("%d\n", !(~( x + !(x + 1) ^ (x + 1))));
}
int main() {
        print (2147483647);
        print(2147483646);
        print(-1);
        print(-2147483648);
}
```

> 1

> 0

> 0

> 0

[*`live demo`*](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ht6xwAXcLIMaTrSE)

Done!

Answer (score 3):

```
int isTmax(int x) {


    //add one to x if this is Tmax. If this is Tmax, then this number will become Tmin
    //uses Tmin = Tmax + 1
    int plusOne = x + 1;

    //add to x so desired input becomes 0xFFFFFFFF, which is Umax and also -1
    //uses Umax = 2Tmax + 1
    x = x + plusOne;

    plusOne = !(plusOne);

    //is x is 0xffffffff, then this becomes zero when ~ is used
    x = ~x;
    x = x | plusOne;
    x = !x;

    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No shifts solution. Realizing to take advantage of the property that `!(0b01111 + 1 = 0b10000) = 0` and `!(0b11111 + 1 = 0b00000) = 1` is particularly tricky. This problem took me a long time.

```c
/*
 * isTmax - returns 1 if x is the maximum, two's complement number,
 *     and 0 otherwise 
 *   Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | +
 *   Max ops: 10
 *   Rating: 1
 */

int isTmax(int x) {

  int a = ~((x + 1) ^ x);
  int b = !(x + 1); 
  int c = !(a + b);

  return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int test(int n) {
  return !(n & 0x80000000) & !~(n | (n + 1));
}

// or just effectively do a comparison

int test2(int n) {
  return !(n ^ 0x7fffffff);
}

int main(int ac, char **av) {
  printf("is%s TMax\n", test(atoi(av[1])) ? "" : " not");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is Tmax : 011111.....

then we xor it with 10000....

we get 11111....

then we ~ to get all 0s = 0 , !0  we get 1:

```
int isTmax(int x) {
  return !(~((1 << 31) ^ x ));
}
```

Comment: please note that `<<` is forbidden in the title

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorter answer based on the newest requirements (i.e., no shifts and no big constants).

```
x + 1 = 0x80000000;
x + (x + 1) = 0xffffffff;
!(~(x + (x + 1))) = 1;
/* Only -1 would fail so we need to explicitly exclude it.*/
```

Final answer.

```
/*
 * isTmax - returns 1 if x is the maximum, two's complement number,
 *     and 0 otherwise
 *   Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | +
 *   Max ops: 10
 *   Rating: 1
 */
int isTmax(int x) {
  int y = x + 1;
  return !!(~x) & !(~(x + y));
}
```