# datalab of CSAPP(isTmax):! seems unoperative

Tags: c, bit, twos-complement

my thought is just like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300650/how-to-find-tmax-without-using-shifts/54060105#54060105).
i code isTmax like this:

```
int isTmax(int x) {
  return  !((~x)+(~x)); // it should be right, the operator "!" seem to not work
}
```

x is 2s complement, 32-bit representations of integers
when i use btest to test function, it generate as follows:

> ERROR: Test isTmax(2147483647[0x7fffffff]) failed...
> ...Gives 0[0x0]. Should be 1[0x1]

**my question is: why 0? it seems like ! not work.**

additionally, i get warning when running btest:

> btest.c: In function ‘test_function’:
> btest.c:334:23: warning: ‘arg_test_range’ may be used uninitialized [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
> 334 |     if (arg_test_range[2] < 1)
> |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
> btest.c:299:9: note: ‘arg_test_range’ declared here
> 299 |     int arg_test_range[3]; /* test range for each argument */
> |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

maybe there is something wrong with my lab environment?

Comment: Signed integer overflow is [undefined behavior](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3p3) -- so that's undefined behavior right there :) - https://onlinegdb.com/3sL952NtsL

Answer (score 0):

This is only a warning message and does not affect your test. You can use `-w` in the makefile to ignore this warning

Comment: This only addresses the warning, but not the more important error message. Please extend your answer.